# Matplotlib: Use colormap AND use different markers for different values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colormap

I currently have a bunch of (x,y) points stored in the array `xy`, that I am colouring using a third array `Kmap`, using matplotlib's in built `cmap` option.

```
plt.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], s=70, c=Kmap, cmap='bwr')
```

This is fine. Now, I want to do something extra. While continuing to use the `cmap`, I want to use different markers according to whether the `Kmap` values are >0, < 0 or =0. How do I do this?

Note: I can imagine breaking up the points, and scatter-plotting them separately, with different markers, using an `if` statement. But then, I don't know how to apply a continuous `cmap` to these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the dataset looks to be a good option. To keep consistency between colors, you may use the vmin, vmax arguments of the scatter method

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


#generate random data
xy = np.random.randn(50, 2)
Kmax = np.random.randn(50)

#data range
vmin, vmax = min(Kmax), max(Kmax)

#split dataset
Ipos = Kmax >= 0. #positive data (boolean array)
Ineg = ~Ipos      #negative data (boolean array)


#plot the two dataset with different markers
plt.scatter(x = xy[Ipos, 0], y = xy[Ipos, 1], c = Kmax[Ipos], vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax, cmap = "bwr", marker = "s")
plt.scatter(x = xy[Ineg, 0], y = xy[Ineg, 1], c = Kmax[Ineg], vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax, cmap = "bwr", marker = "o")

plt.show()
```

Comment: So then, it's the use of `vmin` and `vmax` that are essential to setting the proper limits of the colourmap. That's what was missing in my knowledge. Thanks!